# PgAdmin4 database using on different servers

Tags: server, connection, pgadmin

I have made a nice database in PgAdmin 4 (postgreSql 13). Now I want to use it on an external server. I installed PgAdmin4 (postgreSql13) also on the external server. And I used the same login, and server name.

How can I see the database in the PgAdmin4 on the external server?

Answer (score 0):

You've to host pgAdmin 4 on a server which has access to your PG13 server. You can refer - https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/server_deployment.html for using pgAdmin in server mode.